# Angular - Objects seem bound to eachother but arent

Tags: angularjs, binding

I have an edit page where the user can edit a file in the system, and then save it. When loading the file, I make two objects out of the result, one is bound to the view and the other I wish to keep (in its original state) until "save" is clicked, and then use it to compare vs the view-bound object, to see if any changes have been made.

So, when the page loads, this is being run

```
$http.get('/api/files/' + $stateParams.id)
  .then(function (result) {
      vm.fileTemp = result.data;
      vm.fileTempCopy = result.data;
```

The fileTempCopy is not being touched or referenced by anything in the view or elsewhere in the controller, except in the save-method, where i check if they are alike or not. But somehow, both of them are updated when i make changes to the input fields (as if they were both used as ng-model for the inputs).

```
 if(vm.fileTemp === vm.fileTempCopy)//in save-function
```

is always true, and their fields are exactly the same.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the assignment operator, you are actually just referencing the original array. Arrays are reference types. That means, that they don't actually store values, they only store references to those values.  What you where doing is copying a reference to a memory location, meaning that any changes to the memory at that location (including removing elements) will be reflected in both arrays.

So you will want to do this instead:

```
  vm.fileTemp = angular.copy(result.data);
  vm.fileTempCopy = angular.copy(result.data);
```

Comment: Nice, this works, but im still having problems checking if the object has changed.

Comment: For that, I'm a big fan of the UnderscoreJs library.  You can use _.isEqual(object, other)

Comment: Im using Lodash, works good too :) Accepted your answer as it explained my original issue and got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: @jbrown angular has the same functionality built in, check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals.

Answer (score 0):

here is a very basic approach to checking an object's "value equality".

```
function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    // Create arrays of property names
    var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    // If number of properties is different,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        var propName = aProps[i];

        // If values of same property are not equal,
        // objects are not equivalent
        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we made it this far, objects
    // are considered equivalent
    return true;
}

//After your update Outputs: false
console.log(isEquivalent(vm.fileTemp, vm.fileTempCopy));
```

Comment: Tried this in combination with jbrowns approach to assigning the objects, but it doesnt say they are equivalent even when I dont edit anything before saving.